# Finding ImportJSON Query Path in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Using Google Sheets with the custom [`IMPORTJSON` function](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON), I'm trying to parse the results of [this URL](https://www.wsj.com/market-data/stocks?id=%7B%22application%22%3A%22WSJ%22%2C%22count%22%3A5%2C%22refreshInterval%22%3A300000%7D&type=mdc_fiftytwoweek) so that it returns only the nodes with "highs".

[image]

Using the below formula, where cell `A1` is the above URL, returns a `#REF!` error:

```
=ImportJSON(A1, "/data//highs", "noInherit, noTruncate")
```

I've also tried other variations of the `/data//highs` query (which would usually work with the `IMPORTXML` function) in the formula with the same result.

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

The query should result in displaying the records under "highs", i.e., both `/data/nasdaq/highs` and `/data/nyse/highs`.

The below image is the output for `/data/nasdaq/highs`.  I'm looking to combine that query result with that for `/data/nyse/highs` in a single call.

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you visually clarify what is the structure of the desired output?

Comment: The desired output would be only the arrays under "highs", i.e. `/data/nasdaq/highs` and `/data/nyse/highs`.  I hope this helps clarify the question.

Comment: Hi, my question about visually clarifying this was more about the specific structure of rows and columns as well as the header names and columns should this return. Would each element in `highs` have its own column, so for example there would be a `Nasdaq Highs Type` column? Also, I assume `nyse` and `nasdaq` elements would never be part of the same row?

Comment: I've added an image of the desired columnar output.  Note that the image is the result of using query `/data/nasdaq/highs` and thus excludes `/data/nyse/highs` results, which both should be combined in a single call.  I believe if the source data were in XML format, the XPath for the query would be `//data/*/highs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using ImportJSON:

One option could be to just separate both queries by a comma:

```
=ImportJSON(A1, "/data/nasdaq/highs,/data/nyse/highs", "noInherit, noTruncate")
```

This has several potential downsides, though: it won't automatically detect any additional ticket that has `highs`, but just `nasdaq` and `nyse`. If you wanted others, you'd have to edit your query.

Also, it will return `nasdaq` and `nyse` values in multiple columns, which I assume is not what you want.

#### Writing an alternative function:

Alternatively, since `importJson` cannot handle queries like `//data/*/highs`, I'd suggest writing a different [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) to handle this. To do this, select `Extensions > Apps Script` and copy the following function (see inline comments):

```
function altImportJson(url, query) {
  const jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); // Get data
  let object = JSON.parse(jsondata.getContentText());
  const levels = query.split("/").filter(String); // Get query levels
  for (let i = 0; i < levels.length; i++) { // Iterate through query levels
    const current = levels[i];
    const last = levels[i-1];
    const next = levels[i+1];
    if (current != "*" && last != "*") object = object[current]; // Regular level, not "*"
    else if (current == "*") { // Handle "*"
      object = Object.values(object)
                     .filter(o => o[next])
                     .map(o => o[next])
                     .flat();
    }
  };
  const headers = [...new Set(object.map(item => Object.keys(item)).flat())];
  const data = object.map(item => { // Transform object to 2D array
    let row = new Array(headers.length);
    const entries = Object.entries(item);
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      const columnIndex = headers.indexOf(entry[0]);
      if (columnIndex > -1) row[columnIndex] = entry[1];
    });
    return row;
  });
  data.unshift(headers);
  return data;
}
```

After copying this function and saving your script, you can now call it:

```
=altImportJson(A1, "//data/*/highs")
```

[image]

Comment: The `AltImportJson` script works as intended.  Thanks also for noting usage of commas for multiple `ImportJson` queries.